# Assigning value to module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

I am reading about module.exports in [Node.js Design Patterns](http://www.nodejsdesignpatterns.com/). In this book, it is mentioned that:

> Reassigning the exports variable doesn't have any effect, because it doesn't change the contents of module.exports, it will only reassign the variable itself.

The following code is therefore wrong:

```
 exports = function() {
   console.log('Hello');
 };
```

I am not able to understand why the above assignment is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the local `exports` variable by doing this. Which is local to the [wrapper function](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/bootstrap_node.js#L426-L429) around each Node.js file. There is no way for V8 to know what modification you made to the original `exports` object as you are using a new object.

What you want to do is overwrite the `exports` key in the `module` object.

```
module.exports = function() {
  console.log('Hello');
};
```

For more convenience you could also assign to the `exports` variable so that you can leverage it locally: `module.exports = exports = ...`. That really what `exports` is, a faster way to access `module.exports`.